# What is the reason for the existence of real numbers? Is it an artifact/side effect of our thought process?

Tags: real-numbers, math-history, rational-numbers, foundations

The observation of lengths that can not be represented by rational numbers was noticed if I recall correctly by some Pythagorean disciple over applying the Pythagorean theorem on a triangle with side units of $1$ and realizing that there is no choice for a rational number that when squared is $2$. This discovery led to the real number set.
May be it is a silly question, but I was wondering if this (real numbers) is a side-effect/consequence of how we have structured/invented our number system e.g. base $10$ or if not, how can it be explained in such basis?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130865/discussion-on-question-by-jim-what-is-the-reason-for-the-existence-of-real-numbe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether mathematics is invented or discovered and whether its constructs are "real" are interesting philosophical questions.

The Greeks discovered(?) that the rational numbers were not sufficient to model the idea of a continuous geometric line of points.

That kind of line turns out to be interesting mathematically and useful for modeling physical phenomena. So mathematicians have spent a lot of time figuring out how to describe such an object using the rational numbers and some kind of limiting process. Infinite decimals in base $10$ are one such way.

Comment: The this is an "attribute"/artifact/side-effect of how we create our model of the physical phenomena? Or is it something that we couldn't have avoided?

Comment: May be I am asking this the wrong way. If we have a wall we can use a plumb line and confirm it is vertical to the ground. And we can find an area of the ground that is flat. Hence the wall forms a right angle with the ground. If the wall is $1$ meter and we also measure $1$ meter of the ground and lean a board that board is $\sqrt 2$ meters. We can take the board and measure it, but that board can never be measured precisely with any kind of instrument even though we can find the board's edges? Or that issue exists only in the "model"?

Comment: You can think of physical measurements as rational numbers that approximate some underlying physical truth. So your one meter vertical and horizontal measurements are only approximately $1$ meter. The diagonal will be approximately $\sqrt{2}$ meters. The model you are testing with these measurements is Euclidean geometry.

Comment: When you say that the wall is only approximately $1$ meter, do you mean because we have arbitrarily defined what $1$ meter is? Or because if we had a more accurate measurement instrument we wouldn't have found it to be exactly $1$ meter? If I understand your description it is the mapping of the physical world to the model that creates this existence of real numbers, is that right? So is this caused by the mapping itself, the model we are using or something else?

Comment: When you measure your meter the answer is a number with at $\pm$ something error. You can't know anything is exactly one meter long. I don't believe that it's the mapping of the physical world that creates the real numbers, though that might be considered the motivation for mathematicians to do the creation. Final note: we don't know that the real world obeys Euclidean geometry. The general theory of relativity suggests not. Continue this discussion with a philosopher.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations